# MVC View links stored in config

Tags: sitefinity

Is there config setting that I can use as links within sitefinity MVC view? So I have `a href's` in my view that i dont want to hardcode them in the view cshtml file.

```
<a href="ConfigSetting">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make a custom Config Section
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-create-a-new-configuration

Then I always do something like this in a static helper class so I can use it in Views and around the site

```
    public static MyConfig MyConfig {
        get
        {
            return Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Config.Get<MyConfig>();
        }
    }
```

So then it's

```
<a href="@Util.MyConfig.ConfigSetting">
```

Steve

https://www.sitefinitysteve.com

Comment: Do I add them into the UI?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?